Keycloak - fields validation for registration form
In KeyCloak v15.0.2 is there a way to add validation for registration form fields?
For example I want to allow letters and spaces for full name field or no spaces for username.
Most of these rules can be handled by ReGex rules.
I know I can add html attrubutes, but these does not guarantee full validation.
Is there a way to add KeyCloak server validation?
